# POWERBI: how to scale a multi-categories / multiple vales using another table with factors

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I need some help:

I want to scale the first table using the factors of the second table to get the third table:
[image]

The indexes in the first table are repeated (you can think of them as categories).

How can I get the third table using only the Power Query Editor of POWER BI Desktop?

This is the [pbi](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RneIqES8nXLA-UCxeSCgb3W1Q__XdjvF/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Your sample data is wrong, with the index for the Values to Scale not matching that of Scaled Table, but anyway)

Powerquery method using unpivot, merge and then pivot.  This is the code for the **Values to Scale** data, to convert it to be **Scaled Table** using data from **FACTORS** query

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ValuestoScaleData"]}[Content],

// assumes presence of query FACTORS that contains data as shown
FactorTable1 = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(FACTORS, {"INDEX"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
FactorTable2 = Table.ReplaceValue(FactorTable1,"FACTOR ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute"}),

#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index.1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"INDEX", "Index.1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Other Columns","VALUE ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute"}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Replaced Value", {"INDEX", "Attribute"}, FactorTable2, {"INDEX", "Attribute"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Value"}, {"Value.1"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table2", "MULT", each [Value]*[Value.1]),
Rename = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Attribute", each "Scaled "&_, type text}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Rename,{"Value", "Value.1"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "MULT", List.Sum),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Index.1", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index.1"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I suspected the solution was using pivot/unpivot but couldn't find the correct sequence to do it!  (by the way, you are right, it is true that the data is wrong).  Thanks again.